# Retrieving a linked list relation from a starting node

Tags: sql, graph-theory

Imagine we have an Employee - Supervision relation like the image below:

[image: Employee Supervision]

Where we can basically retrieve all "Manager - Employee" relations with:

```
 SELECT E.lastName AS "Employee", M.lastName AS "Manager"
    FROM Employees E LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (Supervisions S INNER JOIN Employees M 
        ON S.managerID = M.employeeID)
      ON E.employeeID = S.employeeID
    ORDER BY E.lastName
```

**How could we retrieve a walk from any specific employee to all employees it supervises?**

Similarly this relation can be abstracted and applied to anyone saving a graph using 2 tables in any SQL database and trying to walk it.

This question is based on studies from Tom Jewett (where I borrowed images & examples) https://web.csulb.edu/colleges/coe/cecs/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=recursive.php

Comment: if you mean to retrive something like e1->managed by e2->managed by e3 and so on to the highest level, you'll need a recursive cte

Comment: @RinkeshP yes, but I want the opposite: e1 -> supervises e2 -> supervises e3 and so on to the lowest level :) Can you show a recursive cte?

Comment: If you can provide the insert queries for the table or even for the result of the query you mentioned, I can give it a try. Unlike the other way round, this would result in multiple rows (constructing a tree).